# Loop over columns in DF and calculate sum based on condition for every appended column in R or Python

Tags: python, r, loops, combinations, apply

```
A B C
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 1 1
```

Here I have 4*3 dataframe (columns A,B,C). I`d like to calculate sum in a combination of columns based on a condition that both rows are 1. In other words, in the output I want to have 1*3 dataframe with A 2 B 1 C 1. So, first I look at column A, it has 2 rows with ones, so the sum is 2, then I look at combination of A and B, there is just one row with BOTH 1, so I get 1. Finally, I get combination of A,B,C and it has one row with all ones, so I get 1 as well. Could you pls help with the best way to do it in R or Python.

Comment: So what are you seeking help with, `r` or `python`? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: For me, solutions in any of those 2 languages would work. I am trying to find quick solution in R now, so I am first looping over all columns in df, making a list of appended cols A, AB, ABC, then checking condition that row should contain all ones to be counted, calculating sum if condition is satisfied and returning final df as output

Comment: @Dima you can accept any one of the answer from below by clicking on the green check mark next to vote button on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the results in a Series, you can do something like this. a `dict` or `OrderedDict` would be easy too

```
results = pd.Series(index=df.columns)
for i, idx in enumerate(df.columns, 1):
    results[idx] = df.iloc[:,:i].all(axis=1).sum()
```

> results

```
A    2.0
B    1.0
C    1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As a 1-line dict comprehension using `cumsum`

```
d = {col_name: sum(col == i) for i, (col_name, col) in enumerate(df.cumsum(axis=1).iteritems(), 1)}
```

yields:

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}
```

If you want a Series:

```
pd.Series(d, index=df.columns)
```

This only works if the value you are looking for is `1` (or `True`)

Comment: I know, but according to me, this is a different answer which uses a different technique. This one sums all the values, and checks whether the sum corresponds to the column number (+1), so this one would not work if the value in the original DataFrame is something other than 1 (or `True`). The other one counts the `True`-ty values in each column, so you also could replace it with some other check than just `bool()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have 1's and 0's in the dataframe. You can do this in R using `sapply`.

```
sapply(seq_along(df), function(x)  sum(rowSums(df[1:x]) == x))

#[1] 2 1 1
```

Here we incrementally go on selecting one-one column from the dataframe and count the number of rows which all have 1's in them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which is consecutively multiplying the values in each row from left to right using the `Reduce()` function. The codes below require that there are only 1's and 0's in the data.frame.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, Reduce(`*`, .SD, accumulate = TRUE)][, lapply(.SD, sum)]
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 V3
> 1:  2  1  1
> ```

The result is a data.table. If a vector is required, try

```
setDT(DF)[, Reduce(`*`, .SD, accumulate = TRUE)][, unname(sapply(.SD, sum))]
```

> ```
> [1] 2 1 1
> ```

#### Data

```
DF <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), B = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    C = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```